# Replicating iPhone's Photos App

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiscrollview

I'm looking to replicate the iPhone Photo's app behaviour, where it letterboxes the picture when zoomed out, but when zoomed in the bars no longer exist. What view layout (and math) do I need to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: See https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`?

Answer (score 1):

This [MWPhotoBrowser github project](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) is probably your best bet. We looked at doing the same but it really was quite a big job, so we used this instead. Saved lots of time.